# How can I use the google sheets OR function in conditional formatting with "text does not contain"?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a range B6 to B26 that I'd like to format conditionally when a cell does not contain the words "Assessment","GOAL","or "Delete." This is what I have tried so far, unsuccessfully, in the "Text does not contain" option:

```
=OR("Assessment","GOAL","Delete")
=OR($B6="Assessment",$B6="GOAL",$B6="Delete")
=OR(B:B="Assessment",B:B="GOAL",B:B="Delete") <throws an error>
```

I've tried a few other things that were clearly shots in the dark that I'll not list. What's the solution?

Thanks

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basically just use three different, text does not contain conditional formatting rules for a range, one searching for GOAL, another for Assessment, and lastly looking for Delete... But you could also use custom function instead!

[image: Example of Conditional Formatting using custom function]

**Formula:**

```
=(OR(IFERROR(FIND("assessment",LOWER(A2)),-1) > -1, IFERROR(FIND("goal",LOWER(A2)),-1) > -1, IFERROR(FIND("delete",LOWER(A2)),-1) > -1))
```

Replace the `A2`s in my formula with whatever your top leftmost comparison of your array you are comparing should be. See the `A2` in `A2:A1000` in my Apply to Range box?

I'll explain how it works in a second, but I highly recommend you look into [data validation.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) It can help clear up some confusion if the sheet is shared among several users.

OK so first in my or statement I give an

`IFERROR( something..., value if something throws an error).`

This is because I expect the `FIND` function to give me an error if it can't find the value I'm giving it. `FIND(needle, haystack)`. If it does find the text, it will return the position of the value (or needle) I gave it to find in the text (haystack). And if it doesn't it will return to my `IFERROR` an error and `IFERROR` will return a negative number.

Great, but what if I can't find my needle in the haystack because of capitalization discrepancy's ("Needle", "NEEDLE", "NeEdLe")? I'll just make the entire haystack lowercase, and look for a lowercase "needle". We do this by using the `LOWER` formula

And lastly now we just need to make sure that It is larger than `-1`, and then we're done... with one keyword. We duplicate the function two more times for the additional keywords and wrap it in an `OR`.

Comment: This also works. Good to see a different solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
=REGEXMATCH(B6,"Delete|GOAL|Assessment")
```

or the contrary

```
=NOT(REGEXMATCH(B6,"Delete|GOAL|Assessment"))
```

[image]

Reference : [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292)